# Dropwizard config override

Tags: java, yaml, configuration-files, dropwizard

I am developing a RESTful service with Dropwizard. Now I need deploy it to different environment(test, staging, prod) & data centers(cn, us, etc). As such, it needs different config for different environment/data-center.

Curious how is this usually handled? I could potentially have one config for each env/dc, but in that case, they will have a lot of duplication of common config.

I was expecting that I have a base config, say base.yaml, containing the common configs; And then each environment&DC will have one config, which extend/override the base yaml with their custom config. Is this possible within Dropwizard?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think DropWizard has that feature, but you can always write a small script that composes a few YAML files and starts DropWizard with the result. You can use a simple template engine like [Mustache](http://mustache.github.io/) for it.

`config-template.yml`:

```
# ...
server:
  applicationConnectors:
    - type: http
      port: {{PORT}}
```

`config-parms-us.yml`:

```
---
PORT: "8080"
---
```

And then use:

```
mustache config-parms-us.yml config-template.yml > config.yml
java ... server config.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are looking for:
https://github.com/constretto/constretto-dropwizard

It allows you to have environment specific configuration like this:

```
database:   # the JDBC URL   
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-testing:1521/name   
    .staging.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-staging:1521/name   
    .production.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oracle-production:1521/name
```

When you want to start your application with certain environment use:

`-DCONSTRETTO_TAGS=$ENVIRONMENT`

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own configuration bundle which implements `Bundle` to add your own configuration settings.

So you also need to create your own `ConfigurationSourceProvider`, then override the `open(String path)` method, so here you can do find your configuration basename.

Finally you can implements `EnvironmentAware` which can help you resolve all your configuration files which is a list of url. And you can set your default name you want to loaded.